# Xcode + remove all breakpoints

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

Is there any way to remove all the breakpoints in Xcode?

Answer (score 352, accepted):

Well there's a 3 step way:

1. Press CMD(⌘)+7 to show all breakpoints.
   In Xcode4 press CMD(⌘)+6, in Xcode3 press CMD(⌘)+ALT+B.
2. Select all breakpoints with CMD(⌘)+A and delete them, like deleting text, with backspace.
3. There's no step 3 :)

Comment: In Xcode 4, this doesn't show or delete all breakpoints, just some of them.  Try adding a breakpoint from the command line, and you'll see that it doesn't show up in this list.

Comment: On xcode 4.6.3 just go to breeakpoints tab on the left panel, select all using shift+click and delete them using delete key

Comment: How about how to do it without a keyboard shortcut?  Also, there isn't an alt key on Mac, so your Xcode 3 method isn't valid.  and do you mean CMD 7 or CMD F7?

Comment: This answer is out of date.

Answer (score 129):

Its very easy to do in new Xcode. Just click on breakpoints Tab then select all then delete.

**Xcode 10 Screenshot:**

[image]

**Old Xcode Screenshot:**

[image] tap. See attach image for clear reference.

---

Comment: @AndrewKoster Hey its same in Xcode 10 also...what's wrong ? Just Icon in screenshot look bit different...but works same in all Xcode

Comment: I guess my comment got deleted? Anyway, I reversed my downvote, this works. Looks like you posted new screenshots for people like me who are bad at understanding explanations.

Comment: @iPhoneProcessor Keyboard shortcuts can significantly speed up interaction with programs. Provided the program extensively supports keyboard shortcuts, you can usually navigate a lot further in the time it takes to reach for and move the mouse alone. It doesn't make life complex, I'd argue it does the exact opposite, especially if the shortcuts stay the same while the UI changes. It also saves time to find the button if you have no idea where it is, or the buttons are moved around after an update.

Answer (score 23):

In Xcode, you can also do by right clicking the project name on the breakpoints tab and then you can see the options for deleting all breakpoints including disabling and sharing breakpoints.

[image]

Comment: This is out of date.

Comment: @AndrewKoster, even in the **latest Xcode 9.4**, it's working dude. Go to breakpoints tab, right click the project name, it'll show the above options including delete breakpoints.

Comment: You're right, I glossed over the "on the breakpoints tab" part of your answer, because I never use the breakpoints tab and I don't think I was aware of its existence. I was just right-clicking on the project in the normal project view.

Answer (score 22):

In Xcode 4, in the debugger console, type "breakpoint delete" or "br del" for short:

```
(lldb) br del
About to delete all breakpoints, do you want to do that?: [Y/n] y
All breakpoints removed. (1 breakpoints)
(lldb)
```

You can't rely on the GUI breakpoint list, since nothing you enter from the command line will show up there.

Comment: Thanks! I was searching for the LLDB command for that, and I found your answer, which works perfectly in the terminal! +1!!

Answer (score 14):

Other ways:

- Select Breakpoints group in Groups and Files tree, click in Detail view, Command-A, Delete
- Disclose Breakpoints smartgroup in Groups and Files tree, shift- or command-select breakpoints in outline, press Delete
- Run > Console, when app is paused, type "delete breakpoints" and press Return

Answer (score 12):

Xcode 10

> The most easiest way is to do ⌘ + y to disable enable breakpoints .

There is another way

> go to Xcode project navigations pane
>
> Click on show Breakpoint navigator

[image]

> Right click on the project file and select disable all break points

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In Xcode 9 it's CMD(⌘) + 8 to access all breakpoints, you can also just click here:

[image: Sidebar when running the app]

Then you can select and delete them.

Comment: This is the acceptable response today, so heres my upvote.

Answer (score 6):

Additionally, you can customize your Toolbar and put the "Breakpoints" button there. Click this on/off will active/deactivate all breakpoints. While this doesn't remove them, it may be useful if you just don't want them to be hit for a run.

Answer (score 5):

For XCode 12:

1. Press CMD ⌘ + 8
2. Select All (CMD ⌘ + A)
3. Right Click and Select "Delete Breakpoints"

Answer (score 5):

For XCode 12.4

1. Click on **Debug** in Toolbar
2. Choose **Breakpoints**
3. Then Click on **Delete All Breakpoints**

That's it!!

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to mxg 's answer above:

in Xcode 5 it's been changed to CMD(⌘) + 7

Answer (score 4):

For Xcode 5:
In ToolBar, select **Navigate** -> select **Reveal in Project Navigator** -> In **Navigator area**, select **Show the Breakpoint Navigator**.

Here, You can edit, hide/unhide, share, move the breakpoint for each and every class.

Note: Because of Xcode newbie's, am explained the steps from toolbar to show the Breakpoint Navigator.

Answer (score 1):

CMD(⌘) + a 
CMD(⌘) + / 
CMD(⌘) + /

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 7 you can just drag a bp into the project view window and an X will appear, release mouse and it will be deleted.