# Xcode 4.3.2 IBAction button Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1 error

Tags: ios, xcode

So I am getting a thread error Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1 in my IBAction function. The code runs without error, but when I click the button on the simulator, the simulator crashes and produces the breakpoint error. The affected code is:

```
-(IBAction)ChangeView:(id)sender{
SecondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" 
bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:SecondView.view];}
```

I have three other IBActions on the same class which work fine. I also defined in the h file as well.

```
-(IBAction)ChangeView:(id)sender;
```

I don't have much experience with thread errors and getting a bit frustrated trying to fix this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what's the actual error message? only thing we can tell it could be from your code is that you don't declare `SecondView` anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you have a breakpoint set on your function. Follow the instructions on [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665744/xcode-remove-all-breakpoints) to remove the breakpoints.

I don't think your simulator is crashing, I think the execution is just pausing.  You should be able to continue by hitting the play button or typing "c" in the console.