# Thread breakpoint error at custom function

Tags: objective-c, xcode, expression

I am trying to compile this simple program on Xcode 5 and I'm getting a "thread 1: breakpoint 1.1" message at error line below. Anyone know how I can fix it?

Here's my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int totalSavings(int listTotal);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        int itemEntry, itemEntry1, itemEntry2,
        listTotal, calcSavings;

        itemEntry = 320;
        itemEntry1 = 218;
        itemEntry2 = 59;
        listTotal = itemEntry + itemEntry1 + itemEntry2;
        calcSavings = totalSavings(listTotal);          \\error line
        NSLog(@"Total Planned Spending: %d \n Amount Saved: %d", listTotal,
        calcSavings);             
        }
    return 0;
}

int totalSavings(int listTotal)

{
    int savingsTotal;
    savingsTotal = 700 - listTotal;
    return savingsTotal;
}
```

Comment: Remove `int` from the line causing the error.

Comment: Suggestion: Get a good book on the "C" language and study it--that is what I did.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665744/xcode-remove-all-breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

Including the type `int` in the call is incorrect syntax.

The line in error:

```
calcSavings = totalSavings(int listTotal);
```

The fixed line:

```
calcSavings = totalSavings(listTotal);
```

The error message is:

```
Untitled.m:16:36: error: expected expression  
        calcSavings = totalSavings(int listTotal);          // error line  
                                   ^
```

Notice the "^" just under `int`, this is a clear indication of where the error is.