# iOS noob: application halts at NSLog when I click button?

Tags: ios

I have an a button that has an outlet to a method in my controller.m file:

```
    @implementation EMHomepageController
    - (IBAction)firstButtonClick:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"task label text = %@", self.taskLabel.text);
    }
```

However, when I click the button, my file opens and xcode highlights my     `NSLog(@"task label text = %@", self.taskLabel.text);` line in green with a extra green box with text: `Thread 1: breakpoint 1:1`. Also, the button (in the simulator) becomes faded and unclickable. Did I do something wrong?

I'm just trying to print the text of my label in the console. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I'm a beginner

Comment: I did not down vote it but really? You can't figure it out yourself? Don't you understand the meaning of `breakpoint`?

Comment: I up voted because at least he wrote a clear enough question that someone who *did* know breakpoints was able to provide an answer quickly.

Comment: Why would he know what a breakpoint is?  that sort of thing is tough when you're beginning.  The question is well written. @Edmund here's some useful stuff http://stackoverflow.com/a/17622571/294884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a manually placed breakpoint.  In the left margin, where the line numbers are, you should see a blue arrow.  Right click it and disable/delete it and try again.