# Prints statements crash all time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, printing, frameworks

I have an iOS app written in swift which use a linked C framework , all print statement cause the app to crash with error "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1022cd9bc)" even if I print empty statement, however if I changed the print() to NSLog it work. I wonder what could be the issue for such problem.[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnwUf.jpg)

Comment: There is no output in the console it only shows this error in the code Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1022cd9bc)

Answer (score 0):

You have breakpoints active. Just delete or disable them

[image]

[Image Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17622571/8374890)

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by deleting a statement which has a pointer which cause bad memory access